# PHP - Fatal error: Call to undefined method Student_Model::getData()

Tags: php

I am new to the codeigniter.i create a database and run it wamp server. It shows error as

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method Student_Model::getData() in
> C:\wamp\www\sundayclass\application\controllers\student.php on line 8

Can anyone help me understand this error?

This is my controller:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Student extends CI_Controller {

   function index()
        {
            $this->load->model('Student_model');
            $data['result'] = $this->Student_model->getData();
            $data['page_title'] = "CI Hello World App!";
 
            $this->load->view('Student_view',$data);
        }
    
}
```

This is my model.php:

```
<?php
class Student_Model extends CI_Model
{
    function Student_model(){
        //call the model constructor
        parent::__construct();
        }
        
}function getData()
        {
            //Query the data table for every record and row
            $query = $this->db->get('data');
             
            if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
            {
                //show_error('Database is empty!');
            }else{
                return $query->result();
            }
        }
```

This is my view

```
<html>
<head>
    <title><?=$page_title?></title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php foreach($result as $row):?>
    <h3><?=$row->id?></h3>
    <p><?=$row->name?></p>
    <br />
    <?php endforeach;?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Looks like your `getData` method is outside `Student_Model` class.

Comment: i correct it and run.now it shows error as"A Database Error Occurred

Error Number: 1146

Table 'db_matrix.data' doesn't exist

SELECT * FROM (`data`)

Filename: C:\wamp\www\sundayclass\system\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 330".i dont know how to correct it.

Comment: This means that there is table called `data` which is not found in your database `db_matrix`..

Comment: thnx.i correct it.but it shows another error called"A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Filename: views/student_view.php

Line Number: 6". i.m fedup of this.please help me

Answer (score 0):

function `getData()` should be under "student_model" class.

Comment: yah.i correct it. now it shows error as "Error Number: 1146

Table 'db_matrix.data' doesn't exist

SELECT * FROM (`data`)

Filename: C:\wamp\www\sundayclass\system\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 330" how i correct it.

Comment: your query is not right. and may be your your column name not matched with  database table column name.